# Adjective that expresses the scale/range of a noun

Tags: word-choice

Imagine that each country has a central library and that there is a system that will connect all of them with each other.

How can I say that

> "this is a system that connects (the libraries that are on a country basis)".

What's another way of stating the expression in parenthesis - **connects libraries on a country basis**?

example: on the basis of ... / based on ... / on a ... level / by ... / at the scale of ...

Comment: _National_ libraries, or libraries on a _national_ level?

Comment: Is the system interconnecting national libraries or providing a common access to all libraries content ? In telecom, the expression "interconnecting national networks" is often used. For example: *Standards for interconnecting national networks are established by the International Telecommunication Union (ITU)*.

Answer (score 1):

You could say, "... that connects the libraries *nationwide*".

> **Nationwide** *adjective and adverb*
>   Throughout the whole nation: [as adjective]: *a nationwide hunt* [as adverb]: *the company employs 6,000 people nationwide*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nationwide)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for **Intranationally** from:

> **Intranational**
>   [*in-truh-nash-uh-nl*]
>
> *adjective*
>   1.
>   within one nation; occurring or existing within a nation's boundaries.
>
> Related forms: 
>   intranationally, *adverb* - [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/intranational)

Comment: I have thought about a similar word (national) but my question is about the general use of the other words I have listed above--in case the example does not have a one-word alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct word would be **international**. There are plenty of examples where the *inter-* prefix (meaning "between" or "among) is used to describe similar interactions. The *national* suffix conveys that this interaction is on a country basis.

> **International**: involving two or more countries : occurring between countries

- [Merriam-webster dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/international)

E.g. international airports, the Internet connects multiple networks, etc...

If you're referring to the breadth of a system that would connect multiple countries' libraries then you may want to use **multinational**:

> **Multinational**: of, relating to, or involving more than two nations

- [Merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multinational)